# Displaying a Certain Time Frame of a Video in HTML

Tags: html

Is it possible to display a picture from a certain time frame of a video, without initially saving that time frame as a picture? I had similar Project using Python, which could be easily done using OpenCV, but im lost when it comes to HTML...

Thank you for the feedback

Comment: No, you can't do it via HTML as HTML is just markup language without any logic in it (similar to json or CSV)

Comment: ahh such a shame. but thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done using plain HTML. But it can be done with the help of Javascript if you want.

Refer to this [blog post](https://cwestblog.com/2017/05/03/javascript-snippet-get-video-frame-as-an-image/). You can update it according to your specific requirements.

Comment: I will give the post a look. Thank you!